# Why style.backgroundImage returns empty?

Tags: javascript, dom

So here is the HTML

```
<button class="w drum">w</button>
<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And This is the CSS

```
.w {
  background-image: url("images/tom1.png");
}

.a {
  background-image: url("images/tom2.png");
}

.s {
  background-image: url("images/tom3.png");
}

.d {
  background-image: url("images/tom4.png");
}

.j {
  background-image: url("images/snare.png");
}

.k {
  background-image: url("images/crash.png");
}

.l {
  background-image: url("images/kick.png");
}
```

Lastly this is the javascript

```
for (let i in document.querySelectorAll(".drum")) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}

function handleClick() {
    var url = this.style.backgroundImage;
    console.log(url);
}
```

So when I click on w / a / s / d / etc. button, Console should return the image url right?

But this is what happened...

[Console log shows empty string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfqZH.png)

Why is it empty??? Plz help

Comment: The `style` property of an `HTMLElement` returns the values of the *inline* `style` attribute of an element. You need to get the *computed style* of the elements with [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: @EmielZuurbier So URL is a computed style, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and [Window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
const handleClick = (evt) => {
  const url = getComputedStyle(evt.currentTarget).backgroundImage;
  console.log(url);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".drum").forEach((elDrum) => {
  elDrum.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});
```

Comment: I did not know function can be defined by using const, new things to learn everyday i guess. And 'evt.curentTarget' is the same as 'this', right? Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: @Kuncung you guessed exactly right one of the hardest-to-grasp concepts and differences between *regular* `function`s and "fat" Arrow functions. Indeed, Arrow functions have no *knowledge* of `this` since they cannot bind. Therefore we make use of the `Event` argument and extract the "this" by using `Event.currentTarget` - being the Element on which the listener is attached to; vs i.e: `Event.target` which instead is the exact element that propagated the Event (which could be i.e. its child element). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Answer (score 1):

```
import { createApp, markRaw } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'


import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vue3GoogleLogin from 'vue3-google-login'


import './assets/style.css'


const app = createApp(App)

app.use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
    clientId: '433430770978-3pff7bk6ff4qmcc8qnvpckqil6q17bg2.apps.googleusercontent.com'
})
const pinia = createPinia()


pinia.use(({ store }) => {
store.router = markRaw(router)
})

app.use(router)
app.use(pinia)

app.mount('#app')
```

di dalam router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'


const routes = [
  {path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home},
  {path: '/menu', name: 'menu', component: Menu},
  {path: '/login', name: 'login', component: Login, beforeEnter:(to, from, next) => {
    if(!localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
      next()
    } else{
      next('/')
    }
  }},
  {path: '/register', name: 'register', component: Register, beforeEnter:(to, from, next ) => {
    if(!localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
      next()
    } else{
      next('/')
    }
  }},
  {path: '/menu/:id', name: 'detail', component: Detail},
  {path: '/favorite', name: 'favorite', component: Favorite, beforeEnter:(to, from, next) => {
    if(localStorage.getItem("access_token")){
      next()
    } else{
      next('/')
    }
  }},
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})


export default router
```

di dalam store nya

```
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAppStore = defineStore("app", {
  state: () => ({
    isAuth: false,
    foods: [],
    food: {},
    favorite: [],
  }),
  getters:{},
  actions:{
    checkAuth(){
      this.isAuth = !!localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    },

// tempat methode terjadi
    

  }
})
```

di dalam component:

```
import {mapActions, mapState, mapWritableState } from "pinia"
import { useAppStore } from './stores/app'

export default{
    name: "Register",
    components:{},
    data(){
        return{
            data:{
                email: "",
                password: "",
                phoneNumber: "",
                address: "",
            }
        }
    },
    computed:{
      ...mapState(useAppStore,["var"])
    },
    methods:{
        ...mapActions(useAppStore, ["var"])
    },
    created(){
        
        
    }
}
```